# React request to Spring Boot database fails due to Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Here is the security config from the Spring Boot backend:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig
{
    
    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;
 
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT","OPTIONS","PATCH", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        
        
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,  "/api/users").permitAll()
                 requestMatchers("/api/authority").hasAuthority(Constants.ADMIN)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .sessionManagement(s -> s
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            )
            .cors()
                .configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration)
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic();
               
        http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Here is the failed request in javascript React:

```js
const headers = {}
headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + btoa("root:root");
const res = await fetch("http://localhost:7979/api/users", headers);
console.log(res);
const data = await res.json();
console.log(data);
```

the spring backend is run on `localhost:7979` and the React app is run on `localhost:3000`. Also, maybe important, I am on Windows and run the React app on Windows Subsystem for Linux but the Spring app uses the default runner of Intellij.

I'm quite stumped and I can't figure out how to debug Spring Security, everyone just says enable logging which I have done but the Spring Security logging offers 0 useful info (unless I don't understand what I'm seeing)

## Update:

I found a way to activate logging on Spring Security, here are the logs for a successful request:

```
2023-01-26T06:04:15.985+02:00 DEBUG 9708 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/users
2023-01-26T06:04:16.069+02:00 DEBUG 9708 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-01-26T06:04:16.070+02:00 DEBUG 9708 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=gr.hua.dit.it22023_it22026.models.SecurityUserDetails@6bb270f7, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=172.20.196.70, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ADMIN]]
2023-01-26T06:04:16.071+02:00 DEBUG 9708 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /api/users
```

And here are the logs for a failed request:

```
2023-01-26T02:02:23.041+02:00 DEBUG 17932 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/users
2023-01-26T02:02:23.042+02:00 DEBUG 17932 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-01-26T02:02:23.042+02:00 DEBUG 17932 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-01-26T02:02:23.042+02:00 DEBUG 17932 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@456e1a23
2023-01-26T02:02:23.042+02:00 DEBUG 17932 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-01-26T02:02:23.042+02:00 DEBUG 17932 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-01-26T02:02:23.042+02:00 DEBUG 17932 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-01-26T02:02:23.042+02:00 DEBUG 17932 --- [nio-7979-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@456e1a23
```

Screenshot of the request:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The Request but in text , incase you want to copy anything

```
General:
{
Request URL: http://localhost:7979/api/users
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:7979
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
}

Response Headers:
{
HTTP/1.1 401
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2023 11:32:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive
}

Request Headers:
{
GET /api/users HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,el-GR;q=0.8,el;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:7979
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
}
```

I don't understand the fail request logs at all, can any Spring Boot security expert help?

Comment: The failed request doesn't include a BASIC auth header, so no authentication, no access.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added the fetch request to the question, i have an auth header on the request , am i doing it wrong??

Comment: @Ledrake Your screenshot shows that you didn't send an `Authentication` header, so you are not logged in. It looks like your React script is wrong.

Comment: IIIRC, you cannot use `allowedOrigins = *` with `allowCredentials = true`. You'd have to specify your frontend URL, like `allowedOrigins = http://localhost:3000`